# Java 8 filter objects out of list of objects based on a list of other objects

Tags: java, list

I have a list of objects and I have another list of objects, both objects are not the same and generally don't have much to do in common, except that they share one property, that is the same when there is a match. I would like to filter out the entries of one list from the other.

For example:
Object Apple has String property Name and boolean isOrdered.
Object Fruit: has String property Name and boolean available

Say ArrayList apples is filled with entries whose name properties are thus: fuji, pink lady and ArrayList fruits with entries fuji, pink lady, gala, williams, ume.

What I want in the resultslist is a list of fruits containing: gala, williams, ume.

With old java methods this can be achieved with a loop:

```
for (Fruit fruit: fruits) {
  if (!hasEntry(apples, fruit.getName())) {
    result.add(fruit)
  }
}
```

with hasEntry being either being getting all apples from the database and looping over the list or directly looking for the fruitname in the database. Either way is slow.

If the objects were the same I could just use fruits.removeAll(apples). 
java 8 list.filter also only seems to be working for checking the properties if the objects of the own list, not another.

Can filter also be used on two lists with diffrent objects?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like an issue about database access. Your method `hasEntry` probably does retrieve the apples from the ds and compares it to the fruit name. This gets repeated for every fruit which is inefficient.

One way to solve this is by storing the apples in a temporary field and comparing that. You could also retrieve the apples and create a `HashSet<String>` with their names which you can use to compare against the fruit name.

The access time would be O(1) for `HashSet#contains`.

Something like

```
List<Fruits> newFruits = fruits.stream().filter(e -> !hashSet.contains(e.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The HashSet<String> looks like a nice way, I could use a stream map function for extract all the names from the apples list from the database.

Is there also possibly a way to do this in one go, through?